# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Tags: python

I'm trying to find out if a geo point is in polygon. I found [this function](http://geospatialpython.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PiP_Edge.py) online. And I'm trying to pass a list of lat and lon from csv file.

It works when I tried passing variables individually, but run into an error when I put it in the loop.

I'm a newbie in python and have no idea what went wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
data = pd.read_csv('opp.csv')

lat = data['lat'][1]
lon = data['lon'][1]
print lat, lon, type(lat), type(lon)
zone1 = point_in_poly(lat, lon, zone1)
print zone1

#This works and return the following
#41.87639 -87.65328 <type 'numpy.float64'> <type 'numpy.float64'>
    OUT

for i in range(2):
    print i
    lat = data['lat'][i]
    lon = data['lon'][i]
    print lat, lon,type(lat), type(lon)
    zone1 = point_in_poly(lat, lon, zone1)
    print zone1
#I got an error as below

 File "point_in_poly.py", line 8, in point_in_poly
    if (x,y) in poly: return "IN"
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

Comment: `poly` is a string, so `(x, y) in poly` makes no sense - how could a tuple possibly be in a string? What were you trying to achieve? Did you want `if all(thing in poly for thing in (x, y)):` (or perhaps `any(...)`)?

Comment: you omit **important** details: what is `zone1`? It should either be something like a list that python can look through to find out whether the `(x,y)` tuple is a member of the list, or some object with an overloaded `__contains__` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second code snippet, look at this line:

```
 zone1 = point_in_poly(lat, lon, zone1)
```

You're assigning return value of the `point_in_poly` (which is string) to the same variable you use as method argument. So, on next iteration `point_in_poly` tries to look (lat, lon) tuple in that saved string and produces that error.

Just modify your code to something like this:

```
result = point_in_poly(lat, lon, zone1)
print result
```